# status bar iOS 13 для modal ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

В моем приложении есть `status bar` с черным текстом. Также у меня есть режим `Present Modally` в одном из моих контроллеров. Но когда я использую `Present Modally`, мой контроллер имеет дизайн карты, и верхняя часть моего фона под `status bar` становится черной, но моя строка состояния не меняет цвет на белый автоматически. Как это исправить?

мой случай:
[image: image in my case]

то, что хочу сделать:
[image: image like I want to do]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В контроллере, который презентуете, пропишите:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Comment: Не помогало это. Проблема решались тем, что удалил в info.plist строчки связанные со statusBar. И в настройках проекта в Status Bar Style поставил default. Но появилась другая проблема. Когда в настройках iOS включается темный режим, то статус бар становится светлым во всем приложении. А мне это не нужно

Comment: @User , что именно было прописано? Если View controller-based status bar appearance NO, то это одна из проблем почему не помогло. Остальные нужно рассматривать детальнее.

Comment: Были 2 строчки `View controller-based status bar appearance NO ` и `StatusBarStyle darkContent`

Comment: Пожалуйста, посмотрите этот вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1180467/status-bar-меняет-свой-цвет-при-активации-темной-темы-для-ios