# status bar меняет свой цвет при активации темной темы для iOS

Tags: ios, swift

В своем приложении я использую изображение как фон для моего контроллера. Мой дизайн приложения одинаковый для темного и светлого оформления iOS. Для `status bar` в настройках проекта поставил: `Status Bar Style - Default`. Больше ничего для `status bar` нигде не использую.

Проблема в том, что когда включается темная тема, мой `status bar` становится белым. А мне нужно чтобы он оставался черным. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у Вас все приложение в одном дизайне, в будущем ничего не планируется, то легче всего прописать в `Info.plist` ключ-значение:

```
Appearance Light
```

Raw:

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>
```

Comment: Мне пришлось добавить в приложение один единственный контроллер, в котором должна поддерживаться темная/светлая тема iOS. Поэтому теперь это мне не совсем подходит. Я задал новый вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1181316/Как-настроить-цвет-status-bar

Comment: Я практически разрешил проблему. Все дело в `navigationBar`. Не могли бы Вы, пожалуйста, посмотреть его обновленную версию и может быть дать свой комментарий - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1181316/Как-настроить-цвет-status-bar