# Как настроить цвет status bar?

Tags: ios, swift

В своем приложении я использую изображение как фон для моего контроллера. Для `status bar` в настройках проекта поставил: `Status Bar Style - Default`. Больше ничего для `status bar` нигде не использую.

Проблема в том, что когда включается темная тема, мой `status bar` становится белым. А мне нужно чтобы он оставался черным.

При этом я не хочу убирать поддержку темного/светлого режима во всем приложении. Поэтому Appearance Light в `Info.plist` мне не совсем подойдет.

**Обновление:**

Если я использую следущий код во `ViewController` все работает как мне надо:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        return .darkContent
    } else {
        return .default
    }
}
```

Но если я в сториборде добавлю `NavigationController` и соединю его с `ViewController`, то этот код перестанет работать и status bar снова станет белым. Как это исправить?

Если я создам класс `UINavigationController` и использую свой код в нем то status bar станет черным как мне и надо, но если в сториборде у меня `NavigationController` -> `ViewController` -> `SecondViewController` и в `SecondViewController` я хочу изменить бар на белый, то ничего не получится...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UINavigationController` - точно такой же контроллер, как и остальные. Сделайте точно так же, как для контроллера с которым все как надо: унаследуйте, переопределите `preferredStatusBarStyle`  и в сториборде задайте этот класс для `UINavigationController`.

К примеру:

```
class MyCustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            return .darkContent
        } else {
            return .default
        }
    }
}
```

Если хотите чтобы все же зависело от текущего контроллера:

```
class MyCustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return topViewController?.preferredStatusBarStyle ?? .darkContent
    }
}
```

Comment: Ошибка Cannot find 'topViewController' in scope. Я погуглил некоторые решения по этой проблеме, но цвет так и не меняется...

Comment: Это разрешило все `topVC = viewControllers.last`